# Split one column with weird string into multiple columns by specific delimiter in single select sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am seeking/hoping for a simpler solution, although I got a working solution already.

But it is hard for me to accept, that this is the only way. Therefore my hope is, that someone who is a good sql poweruser may have a better idea.

Background:

A simple table looking like that:

| weirdstring | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB] | 1 |
| B;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB] | 2 |
| C;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB] | 3 |

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (weirdstring varchar(MAX),
                        ID int);
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
VALUES ('A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]', 1);
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
VALUES ('B;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]', 2);
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
VALUES ('C;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]', 3);
```

All I need in the end is the first 3 "letter-groups" (1-3 letterst) from weirdstring (eg.ID 1 = A,GHL and BH, the rest of the string is not important now) in seperate columns:

| ID | weirdstring | group1 | group2 | group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB] | A | GHL | BH |
| 2 | B;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB] | B | GHL | BH |
| 3 | C;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB] | C | GHL | BH |

What have been done so far is:

1. change all weird delimiters(;+- and potential more) in the string to comma, eliminate the brackets around "letter-groups". REPLACE daisy-chained is being used. So from `A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]` to
   `A,GHL,BH,BC,NA,NB,AB` first.
2. split the new string to columns by comma as delimiter.

The query used is:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.weirdstring,
       t2.group1,
       t2.group2,
       t2.group3
FROM TESTTABLE t1
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT grp1.ID,
                       grp1.weirdstring AS group1,
                       grp2.weirdstring AS group2,
                       grp3.weirdstring AS group3
                FROM (SELECT ID,
                             weirdstring
                      FROM (SELECT ID,
                                   weirdstring,
                                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROWNUM
                            FROM (SELECT ID,
                                         value AS weirdstring
                                  FROM TESTTABLE
                                       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(weirdstring, '[', ''), ']', ''), ';', ','), '+', ','), '-', ','), '.', ','), ',')
                                  WHERE weirdstring IS NOT NULL) splitted ) s1
                      WHERE ROWNUM = 1) grp1
                     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID,
                                       weirdstring
                                FROM (SELECT ID,
                                             weirdstring,
                                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROWNUM
                                      FROM (SELECT ID,
                                                   value AS weirdstring
                                            FROM TESTTABLE
                                                 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(weirdstring, '[', ''), ']', ''), ';', ','), '+', ','), '-', ','), '.', ','), ',')
                                            WHERE weirdstring IS NOT NULL) splitted ) s2
                                WHERE ROWNUM = 2) grp2 ON grp1.ID = grp2.ID
                     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID,
                                       weirdstring
                                FROM (SELECT ID,
                                             weirdstring,
                                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROWNUM
                                      FROM (SELECT ID,
                                                   value AS weirdstring
                                            FROM TESTTABLE
                                                 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(weirdstring, '[', ''), ']', ''), ';', ','), '+', ','), '-', ','), '.', ','), ',')
                                            WHERE weirdstring IS NOT NULL) splitted ) s3
                                WHERE ROWNUM = 3) grp3 ON grp3.ID = grp2.ID) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

But I could not believe how much of a query have been created in the end for my small task. At least I believe its small.  I am on an older version (14) of sql-server and therefore I cannot use **string_split** with its third parameter (enable-ordinal)  Syntax:

```
STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator [ , enable_ordinal ] )
```

Note: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 : The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). Beginning with SQL Server 2022 (16.x) Preview, the argument and output column are available in SQL Server.

Is there some other, shorter ways to achieve the same results? I know that topic has been discussed many many times, but I could not find a solution to my specific problem here. Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: *"I am on an older version (14) of sql-server"* You have tagged SQL Server 2014 though; version 14 is SQL Server 2017 (2014 is version 12). What version are you actually using?

Comment: Hmm, the database properties says version 14.0.3451.2, SQL Server 2017 seems to be the right one then, thanks.

Comment: But i cannot save the edits, because some errors regarding my question again :/ im sorry

Comment: *"because some errors regarding my question again"* What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: This is likely due to the values in your tables, such as "A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]". If you put them in code markdown (`A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]`) it likely wouldn't error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using SQL Server 2017 (v.14), so a possible option is the following JSON-based approach. The idea is to transform the stored text into a valid JSON array (`A;GHL+BH;BC,NA-NB,[AB]` into `["A","GHL","BH","BC","NA","NB","AB"]`) using `TRANSLATE()` for character replacement and get the expected parts of the string using `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT
   weirdstring,
   JSON_VALUE(jsonweirdstring, '$[0]') AS group1,
   JSON_VALUE(jsonweirdstring, '$[1]') AS group2,
   JSON_VALUE(jsonweirdstring, '$[2]') AS group3
FROM (  
   SELECT 
      weirdstring,
      CONCAT('["', REPLACE(TRANSLATE(weirdstring, ';+-,[]', '######'), '#', '","'), '"]') AS jsonweirdstring
   FROM TESTTABLE
) t
```

Comment: That did the JOB perfectly, thanks a lot!